# How to insert feature vectors as additional channels in conditional DCGANs

Tags: machine-learning, convolution, gan

I understand that in a fully-connected GAN you can simply concatenate the flattened image and feature vector as input for the network. For convolutional GANs I've read that you should add the feature as an additional channel to your image.

How exactly are you supposed to transform your feature vector to an additional channel? Does each feature gets its own channel, or are they all represented in one channel? Does the size of the feature channel need to correspond with the image size, and if so, with what would you fill up the feature vector to meet that size (zeros? ones?)?